# Why can't I see all my powers in the HUD bar in Mass Effect 1 PC

Tags: mass-effect

So basically I'm playing as a Vanguard and I unlocked Marksman for the pistols and shotguns along with Unity and some other skills. I didn't quick-slot them at first and now, after unlocking another power, I can't find them in the bottom part of my HUD, where my powers are. I can only find the ones I quick-tabbed already. What do I need to do to see these other powers?

Comment: Some of your skills don't equate to powers in ME1, that is to say they're passives.  Could that be why you aren't seeing them?

Comment: so the marskman skills for each weapon type is a passive skill? cause i saw my squad have them in their powers section when i pressed the spacebar

Comment: If it is an active skill (which it sounds like, I can't remember for sure), then it may be due to a bug in ME1 were if you have too many active skills, they don't all show up.

Comment: well that sucks..thank you for the responses though

Comment: @Cosmin I cannot speak to your specific bug, as I have not experienced it myself. However the http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Mass_Effect_Wiki may help you find the answer you seek if nobody here can.

Answer (score 2):

If you have too many unlocked, including some of the achievements, the power selection/wheel runs out of room. This is a bug, but one that won't be fixed if it still exists this long after the game's release.

> There are a limited number of powers on the Power Wheel. ... Your
>   bonus Talent may disappear when you unlock all your abilities. You can
>   work around this by mapping the talent before the power
>   disappears, or by selecting a weapon talent.

(Source: [Mass Effect Wikia - Combat-Related Bugs](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Combat#Combat-Related_Bugs))

Answer (score 0):

If you have weapon specific powers, such as Marksman for the pistol and Carnage for the shotgun, and you have too many powers to display at once on the HUD, then it will show the power specific to the weapon you have equipped at the time.